# Soft vibration, in an app

Tags: windows-phone-8

Okay I'm developing a win phone app, and I have buttons here and there and I want the phone to vibrate when someone hits a button.

I managed to do that with

```
using Windows.Phone.devices.Notification;

VibrationDevice v = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();    
v.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
```

However that vibration is rather strong and annoying to get everytime someone hits a button, I'm wondering, **do we get access to the soft vibration?** Like when someone hits the windows button / back key / search glass - those three buttons have a more soft vibration

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For WP7.1 you could use XNA:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsPhone.Input.GamePad.SetVibration(player, leftMotorStrength, rightMotorStrength)
```

However, for Windows Phone 8 this is not possible.

Please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206994%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shorter timespan. Do some experiments on different devices. You might need to use different values for different devices.

I got a really nice soft vibration from Samsung ATIV Odyssey with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01)`. However, HTC 8X seems to ignore a timespan this short - the results with 0.02 was somewhat inconsistent; 0.03 was a good one.